# knitr-manual.lyx fails to compile on LyX 2.1.2

Tags: lyx, knitr

My error message gives me the following:

An error occurred while running:
Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore "C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX
2.1/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R"
"C:/Users/msl0/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.FReZDFD13868/lyx_tmpbuf0/""knit...
22:31:17.653: Error while exporting format: PDF (pdflatex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

First, update LyX to 2.1.3, then follow the instructions of the solution here [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305072/tikzdevice-cannot-create-lock-file-error-when-using-grid-arrange)

Both of these were required on my system to evade a lock file error with the file located in Dropbox.